# Simplify Django model save() expression

Tags: python, django

Here is the situation:

I have a Django model save() function like this:

```
obj = Model1(attr1=params['attr1'], attr2=params['attr2'], attr3=params['attr3'], …)
```

or this:

```
class MyClass():
    pass

my = MyClass()

…...

obj = Model2(attr1=my.attr1, attr2=my.attr2, attr3=my.attr3...)
```

totally more than twenty attributes.

It's a really long and non-fiendly expression. Better way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer something like this

```
params = {
    'param1': param1,
    'param2': param2,
     ....
}

obj = Model1(**params)
```

Comment: If we use obj = Model1(**params), won't it be obj = Model1('attr1'=params['attr1'], …) ? I mean, it turns to string.

Comment: No, as @alecxe said see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769403/understanding-kwargs-in-python

Answer (score 1):

You can use [setattr()](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#setattr):

```
obj = Model1()
for key, value in params.iteritems()
   setattr(obj, key, value)
```

or:

```
obj = Model1(**params)
```

Also see:

- [Understanding kwargs in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769403/understanding-kwargs-in-python)

Hope that helps.

Comment: If we use obj = Model1(**params), won't it be obj = Model1('attr1'=params['attr1'], …) ? I mean, it turns to string.

Comment: @ray6080, Nope, it would be like `Model1(attr1=params['attr1'],..)` - like normal keyword arguments.